# MATLAB nested parfor indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, parfor

I converted a nested for loo into a unique parfor loop. The nested for loop looked like this:

```
for RIPETIZIONE = 1:N_RIPETIZIONI
   for k=1:size(lambda_tol_vector)
       %do things
   end
end
```

Now, the parfor loop takes on the following values:

```
parfor n=1:N_RIPETIZIONI*K
   [~,k]=ind2sub([N_RIPETIZIONI,K],n);
...
```

hence merging into a single loop the nested loops of before.
Now, inside the "outer" nested loop (`for RIPETIZIONE = 1:N_RIPETIZIONI`), but outside the inner loop (for `k=1:size(lambda_tol_vector)`), there was this part:

```
scv=size(columns_validation_test,2);   
   
for counter_columns = 1:scv
   COLONNA_SELEZIONATA=columns_validation_test(counter_columns);
   Ctest=zeros(size(A.Value));
   Ctest(:,COLONNA_SELEZIONATA)=C(:,COLONNA_SELEZIONATA);
   Cvalidation=C-Ctest;
   for j=1:size(lambdavector)
       RMSE_initial_test{counter_columns}(j)=sqrt(sum2(Diff_sq_initial{j}.*Ctest)/sum(Ctest(:)));
       RMSE_final_corrected_validation{counter_columns}(j)=sqrt(sum2(Diff_sq_corrected{j}.*Cvalidation)/sum(Cvalidation(:)));
       RMSE_final_test{counter_columns}(j)=sqrt(sum2(Diff_sq{j}.*Ctest)/sum(Ctest(:)));
       RMSE_final_corrected_test{counter_columns}(j)=sqrt(sum2(Diff_sq_corrected{j}.*Ctest)/sum(Ctest(:)));
           
   end
       [~,arg_min_temp_1]=min(RMSE_final_corrected_validation{counter_columns});
end
```

which I need now to include in the unique parfor loop with a pope indexing. Fo instance, `Diff_sq_initial`, `Diff_sq_corrected` and `Diff_sq` are all defined within the parfor loop with an index of n in the new loop (whereas previously they were indexed with k inside the `for k=1:size(lambda_tol_vector)` loop).
Is there a way to properly indexing those variables so that they fit the new parfor loop?

Comment: I’m unsure what you’re asking. You already have a way to compute `k` in your parfor loop. And I don’t see a `k` in the inner section of the loop at all.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The point is that RMSE_initial_test{counter_columns} is not accepted within the parfor due to the counter_columns indexing (even if I substitute j with k)

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to split output arrays such that each element of the array is written to in only one loop iteration. This is not always trivial. You might have to rethink your arrays, or your looping strategy.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to work out exactly what it is that doesn't work. Could you perhaps post a simplified but complete `parfor` loop that shows the error, and has all the output types you're after? (My guess is that using the `ind2sub` trick is making it hard to correctly "slice" your loop outputs, but I'm not sure)